# Display WooCommerce products with a shortcode using a custom meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I'm creating a flash sale website and I already display products according to date range on my home and shop pages. But I also want to display products according to a date range elsewhere and therefore using a shortcode.

Here is my code:

```
function testt($meta_query)
{  
$today = current_time('Ymd');
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', array (
'post_type' => 'product',   
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'start_clause' => array(
        'key'=>'flash_sale_start',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare'=> '<=',
     'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
         'end_clause' => array(
         'key' => 'flash_sale_end',
     'value' => $today,
         'compare' => '>=',
     'type' => 'DATE'
     ),
       )));
return $args;
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'testt' );
```

But it doesn't display anything, even the rest of my page content has disappeared.

What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normal that it doesn't return anything as you need to pass this `$args` in a `WP_Query` first and to call a the product template in a loop this way:

```
if( ! function_exists('product_test') ) {

    // Add Shortcode
    function product_test( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        // Attributes 
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'columns'   => '4',
                'limit'     => '20',
                'start'     => current_time('Ymd'),
                'end'       => current_time('Ymd'),
            ),
            $atts, 'products_test'
        );


        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];
        
        // The WP_Query
        $products = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => $atts['limit'],
            'meta_query'        => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                'start_clause'  => array(
                    'key'       =>'flash_sale_start',
                    'value'     => $atts['today'],
                    'compare'   => '<=',
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                ),
                'end_clause'    => array(
                    'key'       => 'flash_sale_end',
                    'value'     => $atts['today'],
                    'compare'   => '>=',
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                ),
            )
        ));

        ob_start();

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
        } else {
            do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results", $atts );
            echo "<p>There is no results.</p>";
        }

        woocommerce_reset_loop();
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    add_shortcode( 'products_test', 'product_test' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

---

**USAGE:**

There is 4 available optional arguments that you can add to this shortcode:

- `columns` (The number of columns) - Default is 4
- `limit` (the number of products | -1 will display all ) - Default is 20
- `start` (Start date | format is 'YMD' ) - Default is today
- `end` (End date | format is 'YMD' ) - Default is today

You can set any more in the function… You can change default values too.

Example 1 (simple with default values):

```
[products_test]
```

Example 2 (some custom values)

```
[products_test columns='3' limit='15']
```

Tested and works